# Faraday::ConnectionFailed: connection refused while saving to mongo database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Hello RoR + Mongo(Mongoid) application here

What is the immediate error msg?

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: connection refused: localhost:9200
```

When does this happen? When I try to save the User instance in console

```
User.create!(email:"kevin@gmail.com",password:"helloWorld123",password_confirmation:"helloWorld123")
```

I would appreciate any help or input. Have a great day & thanks for reading. Below is details of the related code

1) Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.4.1'
  gem 'spring', '~> 1.2.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'faker', '~> 1.4.3'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.3'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.3.0'
  gem 'launchy', '~> 2.4.2'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.43.0'
end

gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.2.7'
gem 'figaro', '1.0'

#for cloud uploads (amazon)
gem 'fog', '~> 1.27.0'
#gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.6'
gem "will_paginate_mongoid", '~> 2.0.1'

#for search
gem 'searchkick', '~> 0.8.5'

# managing events
gem 'sidekiq', '3.3.0'
gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.4.5', require: false
gem 'slim', '~> 3.0.1'

# frontend package management
#source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
#  gem 'rails-assets-bs-typeahead'
#end
gem 'mechanize', '~> 2.7.3'

# user/privelege stuff
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
#gem 'therubyracer' V8 javascript interpreter
gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.2.2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'pundit', '~> 0.3.0'

# DB options
gem "redis", "~> 3.0.1"
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
gem 'mongoid_userstamp', '~> 0.4.0'
gem 'bson_ext', '~> 1.5.1'
gem 'moped', '~> 2.0.3'

# display stuff
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.5'
gem 'rename', '~> 1.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.0.0.pre', github: 'reactjs/react-rails'
gem 'magnific-popup-rails', '~> 0.9.9.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.2'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0.3'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
#gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
gem 'debugger2', :git => "git://github.com/ko1/debugger2.git"

gem 'browserify-rails'
```

User model

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Userstamp::User
  include Connectable, SearchesASCAP, SearchesBMI

  #callbacks
  after_create :populate_data
  after_create :ensure_profile

  #relationships
  has_and_belongs_to_many :songs, dependent: :nullify
  has_and_belongs_to_many :searches, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :profile
  has_one :writer

  has_many :author_conversations, class_name: 'Conversation', inverse_of: :author, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :recipient_conversations, class_name: 'Conversation', inverse_of: :recipient, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  #validations
  validates_presence_of :email, :encrypted_password

  #SEARCH
  searchkick word_start: [:firstname, :lastname, :display_name, :role, :genre],
             locations: ["location"]

  def search_data
    attributes.merge(
      firstname:          firstname,
      lastname:           lastname,
      society_id:         society_id,
      display_name:       profile.try(:display_name),
      role:               profile.try(:role),
      city:               profile.try(:city),
      state:              profile.try(:state_code),
      genre:              profile.try(:genre),
      daw:                profile.try(:daw),
      location:           profile.try(:coordinates)
    )
  end

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :firstname,             type: String, default: ""
  field :lastname,              type: String, default: ""
  field :email,                 type: String, default: ""
  field :encrypted_password,    type: String, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
  field :reset_password_token,   type: String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, type: Time

  ## Rememberable
  field :remember_created_at, type: Time

  ## Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,      type: Integer, default: 0
  field :current_sign_in_at, type: Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,    type: Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip, type: String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,    type: String
  field :signed_up_on,       type: Date, default: Date.today

  # Songwriter information
  field :society_id,         type: String, default: ""
  field :ipi_id,             type: String, default: ""
  field :society,            type: String, default: "ASCAP"

  # for OmniAuth
  field :provider,           type: String, default: ""
  field :uid,                type: String, default: ""
  field :timezone,           type: String, default: ""
  field :access_token,       type: String, default: ""
  field :expires_at,         type: String, default: ""

  ## Confirmable
  # field :confirmation_token,   type: String
  # field :confirmed_at,         type: Time
  # field :confirmation_sent_at, type: Time
  # field :unconfirmed_email,    type: String # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # field :failed_attempts, type: Integer, default: 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # field :unlock_token,    type: String # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # field :locked_at,       type: Time

  default_scope -> {order_by(:firstname.asc, :lastname.asc)}

  # OMNIAUTH
  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
        user.firstname = data["firstname"] if user.firstname.blank?
        user.lastname = data["lastname"] if user.lastname.blank?
     end
    end
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
       user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
       user.provider = auth.provider
       user.uid = auth.uid
       user.email = auth.info.email
       user.firstname = auth.info.first_name
       user.lastname = auth.info.last_name
       user.timezone = auth.extra.raw_info.timezone
       user.access_token = auth.credentials.access_token
       user.expires_at = auth.credentials.expires_at

       Profile.create(
          user: user,
          image: auth.info.image,
          display_name: user.firstname + " " + user.lastname
        ) 
    end
  end

  def full_name
    self.firstname + " " + self.lastname
  end

  def location
    if self.profile.state_code
      self.profile.city + ", " + self.profile.state_code
    else
      self.profile.city
    end
  end

  ## SCRAPING 
  def populate_data
    DiscographyWorker.perform_async(self.id.to_s)
  end

  def ensure_profile
    if self.profile.nil?
      self.profile = Profile.new
    end
  end

  def scrape_discography
    # validate user has entered ascap_id or ipi_id
    if self.society == 'ASCAP'
      populate_ascap
    elsif self.society == 'BMI'
      populate_bmi
    end
  end
end
```

Full Error Trace

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: connection refused: localhost:9200
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:641:in `rescue in connection_for'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:589:in `connection_for'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:994:in `request'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http_persistent.rb:26:in `perform_request'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:40:in `block in call'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http_persistent.rb:22:in `with_net_http_connection'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:32:in `call'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.7/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:21:in `block in perform_request'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.7/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:in `call'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.7/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:in `perform_request'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.7/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.7/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:115:in `perform_request'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.7/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/index.rb:99:in `index'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/searchkick-0.8.7/lib/searchkick/index.rb:44:in `store'
... 20 levels...
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/apprentice/Documents/work/fourleafapp/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/apprentice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure your Elasticsearch is running

Answer (score 0):

whenever user is created updates the indexes in elasticsearch
this was an elasticsearch error and not configuring the port correctly